# Send SMS on behalf of user in Android

Tags: java, android, sms

What do I need to do to both send an SMS message but also have it appear in the user's text messaging apps as if they sent it from the app themselves?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own SMS client.

Or, you can negotiate with every SMS client author out there, to get them to open up an API to allow you to put messages in their app that they didn't send.

Comment: All the SMS apps I've seen share text messages, including the built-in ones and Handcent so I believe there is a centralized database...

Comment: @Josh Patton: Not one that is documented and supported.

Comment: Yet Handcent still manages to have seamless integration and allows users to switch back and forth?

Answer (score 0):

SMS messages can be stored in the SIM card of GSM phones. Perhaps these various SMS message apps are all accessing the SMS messages on the SIM card, effectively providing integration between the apps?